# Direction of motion

Tags: kinematics, terminology, definition

What does the term [direction of motion](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=definition+direction+motion) actually mean?
Is it a direction where a particle is moving or the direction of its velocity?
For example, what is the direction of motion of a projectile in each case when it is moving upward and then downward? 
In each case, the direction of its acceleration is downward.

Comment: How can a projectile be moving upwards when its velocity is downwards? Maybe you are confused between displacement and it time average velocity $\frac{s}{t}$ and the velocity at a specific time $\frac{\delta s}{\delta t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the direction defined by the velocity vector.

What is your definition of "a direction where a particle is moving" of not for the direction of its velocity vector?

Also, what you say about the projectile is false.  The projectile moves along a parabolic path.  Before it reaches its apex, its velocity vector has a vertical component pointing upward, and after it reaches its apex, its velocity vector has a vertical component pointing downward.  The direction of its velocity is *not* downward the whole time.  You may be thinking of its *acceleration* vector which *does* point downward the entire time.

Answer (score 2):

The position of your projectile is a vector, $\vec{r}$, commonly given in component notation as $(x, y, z)$. The velocity, $\vec{v}$, of the particle is also a vector and is given by $d\vec{r}/dt$. The direction of motion is the direction the velocity vector points in.

To take your example of a projectile fired straight up, because only it's height, $z$, is changing the velocity vector will look like:

$$ \vec{v} = (0, 0, \frac{dz}{dt} ) $$

On the way up $dz/dt$ will be positive because the height is increasing, while on the way down $dz/dt$ will be negative because the height is decreasing, so comparing the velocity halfway up and halfway down (and ignoring air resistance):

$$ v_{up} = (0, 0, v_{1/2}) $$

$$ v_{down} = (0, 0, -v_{1/2}) $$

Where $v_{1/2}$ is the magnitude of the velocity halfway to the top of the trajectory.

So $v_{down} = -v_{up}$ - the two velocity vectors point in opposite directions not the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

No that the velocity vector is *always* tangent to the path. So the direction of motion can be viewed as the direction of the velocity vector, as well as the direction of the path at that location. A path has direction because it has a start and a finish.

Mathematically if a path has position vector $\vec{r}(q)$ where $q$ is any independent coordinate such as distance, angle, time, then the direction of motion is defined by

$$\vec{e}(q) = \frac{\vec{r}'(q)}{|\vec{r}'(q)|} $$

where $\vec{r}'(q) = \frac{{\rm d}\vec{r}(q)}{{\rm d} q}$. The velocity vector is defined as

$$\vec{v}(q) = \vec{r}'(q) \;\dot{q}$$

So the direction of motion depends on the direction of the path $\vec{r}'(q)$ and the sign of $\dot{q}$ which indicates if you are moving forwards or backwards on the path.

Welcome to the world of differential geometry.